# Chow groups and short exact sequence

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ and $Y$ be subvarieties of a smooth projective variety $M$ such that $M=X \bigcup Y$. Can you explain to me why $ A_k ( X \bigcap Y ) \to A_k ( X ) \oplus A_k ( Y ) \to A_k ( X \bigcup Y ) \to 0 $, such that $ A_k ( X ) $ is the Chow group of $X$.
Can you tell me if you know some references about this subject ?
Thanks a lot.  :-)

Comment: How are the maps in your sequence defined?  "Proper pushforward" requires <I>proper</I> morphisms.  I recommend that you read the introductory chapters of a good book on intersection theory, e.g., Fulton's book.

Comment: Do you mean to assume (per Jason Starr's comment) that $X$ and $Y$ are closed?  If so, you can (and should!) drop the assumption that $M$ is smooth.

Comment: Yes, $ X $ and $ Y $ are closed. Thank you.

Comment: @JasonStarr:  Actually, Fulton (quite reasonably) states this result without proof, so if the OP doesn't already see how to prove it, Fulton won't help.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg:  I guess I am confused.  For me a "variety" is an irreducible, finite type scheme over some (fixed) field.  So if $M$ is a smooth projective variety, if $X$ and $Y$ are closed subsets, and if $M$ equals $X\cup Y$, then one of $X$ or $Y$ equals $M$, say $X=M$.  Then the sequence is ridiculous.  My suspicion is that, actually, the OP does not know quite what he wants to ask, he has written something a bit absurd, and the readers are struggling to project some meaning on what is written.

Comment: @JasonStarr:  Yes, given that $X$ and $Y$ are closed, the problem is completely trivial unless $M$ is reducible, which is why I said in my earlier comment that the OP can *and should* drop the assumption that $M$ is smooth.  For $M$ reducible the problem is still very easy but (though I wavered back and forth on this) I thought it was worth pointing out the simple argument that the OP might have missed.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg: Okay, now I see what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

We can assume $M=X\cup Y$. (And, per the comments above, we assume $X$ and $Y$ are closed.)

Suppose $x$ and $y$ are cycles on $X$ and $Y$ such that $x+y$ becomes trivial in $A_k(M)$.  A trivialization of $x+y$ restricts in the obvious way to trivializations of $x$ on $M-Y$ and of $y$ on $M-X$.  Thus it restricts to trivializations of $x+z$ and $y+z$ on $X$ and $Y$, for some cycle $z$ supported on $X\cap Y$.